# PHP Table - Get URL addition from table row

Tags: php, variables, url

I have the following table which pulls information from a MySql database and shows in the table perfectly.

[image: table result after search]

However, I am trying to get the image in rows 'Edit Record' and 'Link to Record' to be URL
'''a href="editcandidatecard.php?pr=6050'''

The following:

'''
<?php

```
             if(!$employee_details)
             {
                echo '<tr>No data found</tr>';
             }
             else{
                foreach($employee_details as $key=>$value)
                {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key+1;?></td>
                <td><?php echo '<a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=" ' . $row['payroll_number'] . '</a>'?><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" ></td>                  
                <td><?php echo '<a href="editcandidatecard.php?no="> ' . $value['payroll_number'] . '</a>'?><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" ></td>   
                <td><?php echo $value['payroll_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['title'], '&nbsp;', $value ['first_name'], '&nbsp;', $value ['last_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['mobile_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['home_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['email_address'];?></td>
                </tr>
                    
                    <?php
                }
                
             }
            ?>
```

'''
Gives: [image: table after search URL]

1. The Url shown by:
   ''''?>'''
   Is - editcandidatecard.php?no=
2. The Url shown by:
   ''' ' . $value['payroll_number'] . ''?>'''
   IS - editcandidatecard.php?no=

I want to achieve a url of editcandidatecard.php?no=6050

Where the 6050 is pulled from the value shown in the 'payroll number'

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Open `a` tags are not closed. Here: `<a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=" ' . $row['payroll_number'] . '</a>`.

Comment: Hi Syscall, 
Apologies, i don't understand the above. 
The images are picking up the url 
http://editcandidatecard.php?no=
But the value in the row [payroll_number} is not being picked up to give 
http://editcandidatecard.php?no=6050

Comment: Hi Syscall,
Sorry but this still returns 
editcandidatecard.php?no=
not 
editcandidatecard.php?no=6050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place images between `a` tags like below.

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=" ' . $value['payroll_number'] . ' ">'; ?><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" /></a></td>
<td><?php echo '<a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=" ' . $value['payroll_number'] . ' ">'; ?><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" /></a></td>
```

As a more readable and simple approach, the following snippet can be used.

```
<td><a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=<?= $value['payroll_number'] ?>"><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" /></a></td>
<td><a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=<?= $value['payroll_number'] ?>"><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks Ozan, 
But this is still returning
 editcandidatecard.php?no=
not
editcandidatecard.php?6050

Comment: Is there a chance that you are using $row['payroll_number'] instead of $value['payroll_number'] ? Because, in the next row if it shows 6050 using <?php echo $value['payroll_number'];?> then <a href="editcandidatecard.php?no=<?= $value['payroll_number'] ?>"> must include 6050 to the href inside a tag.

Comment: Hi Ozan,
I am such an idiot, you are so correct. I apologize for my utter stupidity. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Ozan Budak

Complete working code:

'''
<?php

```
             if(!$employee_details)
             {
                echo '<tr>No data found</tr>';
             }
             else{
                foreach($employee_details as $key=>$value)
                {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                
                <td><?php echo $key+1;?></td>
                <td><a href="editcandidatecard.php?pr=<?= $value['payroll_number'] ?>"><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" ></a></td>                    
                <td><a href="candidatecard.php?pr=<?= $value['payroll_number'] ?>"><img src="images/document.gif" height="30" ></a></td>    
                <td><?php echo $value['payroll_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['title'], '&nbsp;', $value ['first_name'], '&nbsp;', $value ['last_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['mobile_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['home_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['email_address'];?></td>
                </tr>
                    
                    <?php
                }
                
             }
            ?>
        
    '''
```